# How should I get file count for only one SharePoint folder in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, powershell-2.0, sharepoint-online

In my SharePoint site, I have two folders called "General" and "Testing2" under Document. I'm trying to get the count only for "General" but not sure why it's still also counting for Testing2 folder so I would be really appreciate if I can get any help or suggestion.

I tried like this, $ListName = "/Shared Documents/General" but still not working

```
#Parameters
$SiteURL = "https://comapny.sharepoint.com/sites/msteams_####/"

//I tried like this but still not working
$ListName = "/Shared Documents/General"
$CSVFile = "C:\Users\kek\Desktop\Resource\LitHold\FolderStats.csv"
 
#Connect to SharePoint Online
Connect-PnPOnline $SiteURL -useWebLogin
  
#Get the list
$List = Get-PnPList -Identity $ListName
 
#Get Folders from the Library - with progress bar
$global:counter = 0
$FolderItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -PageSize 500 -Fields FileLeafRef -ScriptBlock { Param($items) $global:counter += $items.Count; Write-Progress -PercentComplete `
            ($global:Counter / ($List.ItemCount) * 100) -Activity "Getting Items from List:" -Status "Processing Items $global:Counter to $($List.ItemCount)";}  | Where {$_.FileSystemObjectType -eq "Folder"}
Write-Progress -Activity "Completed Retrieving Folders from List $ListName" -Completed
 
$FolderStats = @()
#Get Files and Subfolders count on each folder in the library
ForEach($FolderItem in $FolderItems)
{
    #Get Files and Folders of the Folder
    Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $FolderItem.Folder -Property Files, Folders | Out-Null
     
    #Collect data
    $Data = [PSCustomObject][ordered]@{
        FolderName     = $FolderItem.FieldValues.FileLeafRef
        URL            = $FolderItem.FieldValues.FileRef
        FilesCount     = $FolderItem.Folder.Files.Count
        SubFolderCount = $FolderItem.Folder.Folders.Count

    }
    $Data
    $FolderStats+= $Data
}
#Export the data to CSV
$FolderStats | Export-Csv -Path $CSVFile -NoTypeInformation
```

I don't want to to print Testing 2

[image]

Comment: Are you really using 2.0?

Comment: Did you try url encoding the space in the listname? `$ListName = "/Shared%20Documents/General"`